# Error with print or if in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  1  print("hello world")
  2  myname = input("what is your name?")
  3  print(myname)
  4 if(myname == "ofir"):
  5 print("you are great")
```

This is the code I have written with python (I have just started today).I got this error "expected an indented block" in line 5, I dont know what my mistake.
Thank you for help.I use 3.4.3 python.

Comment: How much of the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) have you followed? Indentation is *fundamental* to the language, and is explaind in the [introduction section](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html). You appear to have *no* indentation, so Python cannot determine where the code part of the `if` block starts or ends.

Comment: I have followed 2 python tutorials and a half from the third.

Comment: Go for http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ i think it's more better for you.

Comment: Also, `if` statements in python don't need parens. `if foo == "bar":` is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2):

You should indent lines of code 4 spaces if it's part of that code block. In python this will include if statements, loops, def, and class. I recommend you read this article: [Python-Indetation](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1312792&seqNum=3). To answer your question, change your code to:

```
 print("hello world")
 myname = input("what is your name?")
 print(myname)
 if(myname == "ofir"):
     print("you are great")  # note the 4 spaces
```

Answer (score 1):

Python requires indentation under `if` statements, as well as `for` and `while` loops, `functions`, `classes`, etc. You appear to be missing indentation. I would consider going through the [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/learn) interactive tutorial for Python

```
print("hello world")
myname = input("what is your name?")
print(myname)
if myname == "ofir":
    print("you are great")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need indentation after your if statement.

And undo the indents for the first three lines of your code.

Answer (score 0):

In C programming language a block of code (instructions) is enclosed in parenthesis. It does not matter the indentation. In Pascal the block is enclosed in 'begin' 'end'. As you have noticed by now in Python the block of instructions contained in an 'if', 'else', 'for', 'while', 'def', etc. statement is not enclosed by anything. Python knows that several instructions are the same block if they have the same indentation.

Indentation can be any number of spaces or tabs and can vary through out the Python script. The only rule is that inside the same block it has to be the same indentations.

Please see the code bellow checked with Python 2.7:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
for e in a :
  if e % 2 == 0 : # indent with 2 spaces
      print "%d is even" % e            # indent with 4 spaces
      print
  else :          # indent with 2 spaces
     print "%d is odd" % e              # indent with 3 spaces
     print
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  1  print("hello world")
  2  myname = input("what is your name?")
  3  print(myname)
  4  if(myname == "ofir"):
  5     print("you are great")
```

You need to indent `print("you are great")` in order for the program to compile